# Javascript Text Resize Problems

Tags: javascript, wordpress, text, resize

I am attempting to use a java script text resize function on a website. But, it is not working. I wonder if any one can spot a coding error that I am not seeing? Thanks!

http://sample.myblackhairstyle.com/ (resizer is in top right hand corner "Make Text Bigger).

In header.php I put:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">function resizeText(multiplier) {
  if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
    document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
  }
  document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
}</script>`
```

Place this where wanted resizer to appear:

Make text bigger | Make text smaller

Comment: From what I can tell, the problem is that most of the other elements on your page already have css styles that define what size the font of those elements is supposed to be.

Comment: I wonder how I could remedy this while still being able to define the initial font size

Answer (score 1):

I can see an error 
**'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < '**

while loading the website from the file 'widgets.js:1' . Firstly you need to work around that.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `resizeText` function with this one:

```
function resizeText(multiplier) {
    if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
        document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
    }
    document.body.style.setProperty(
        "font-size", 
        parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em",
        "important"
    );
}
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/S7qXa/2/).

Anyone know how to get the initial font size of the body element as defined in css?